# T-SQL adding CASE When Then to current SELECT statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, sql-server-2016

Hey all I have this query code below in a stored procedure:

```
/************************************/
/*            The Query             */
/************************************/
SELECT AMTddbox     AS NETWORK                      FROM mainpage_AMTdata
SELECT name         AS TYPE                         FROM typeOf
SELECT name         AS PHASE                        FROM IncrementPhase
SELECT theLevel     AS 'SUPPORT LEVEL'              FROM supportLevel
SELECT location     AS LOCATION                     FROM location

(CASE 
   WHEN 
    (@val1 = 'inventory') 
   THEN 
    SELECT invID        AS inventoryID              FROM invData
    SELECT name         AS invName                  FROM invUsers
END)
```

And of course the T-SQL above does not work because of the error of:

> Procedure spExcelData, Line 30 [Batch Start Line 18]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
>
> Procedure spExcelData, Line 32 [Batch Start Line 18]
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

So how can I go about doing what I am wanting to do in order for me to check if **@val** equals **inventory** or something else? If it **does** equal then I need it to return the other 2 select statements back to me along with the other 5 above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case is an expression. It cannot be used like a statement to control flow. You would need to use an IF statement here.

```
if @val1 = 'inventory'
begin
    SELECT invID AS inventoryID
    FROM invData

    SELECT name AS invName
    FROM invUsers
end
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks Sean!

Answer (score 0):

A CASE expression goes within a SELECT statement, not vice-versa. If the outcome of @val1 for you is going to change the entire structure of your SELECT statement, like using a different table, then you'd want to use an IF/ELSE. If it's just changing which columns/values are returned from the same table, you can use a CASE expression within your SELECT statement:

```
SELECT CASE @val1 WHEN 'inventory' THEN invID ELSE OtherColumnName END as 
myColumn FROM invData
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have 5 distinct result sets, each with a single column. That's perfectly valid, but strikes me as a bit odd if there's no relationships between those tables for which to make a join.

As for the error, you just have a floating `case` statement there. You need to use a case statement in the context of a larger expression such as a `select` or `where` clause (e.g. `select case when @val1 = 'Inventory' then ...`)

Also, a case statement can only return a single scalar value. You can use `case` in a select list, and it will be evaluated on each row, but you can't have either then `when` or `then` be a result set or table. You also can't have it return two results (i.e. your select from `invData` and your select from `investoryId`

If the inline nature of `case` seems to limit you too much, you might just look at a good ol' fashioned `if/else` instead